# Make \cite{my reference} show name and year, with the "naturemag-doi" bibliographystyle

Tags: natbib, author, bibliographystyle, springernature, authoryear

**Question.** How to show authorname and year if using the "naturemag-doi" bibliographystyle?

```
\bibliographystyle{naturemag-doi}
```

**MWE 1.** If I use the "naturemag-doi" bibliographystyle I get an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress,merge,round]{natbib}
% \bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliographystyle{naturemag-doi}
\begin{document}
\citet{Lin}
\bibliography{ms_V1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**MWE 2.** If I use the "apalike" bibliographystyle I only get the authorname, but not the year:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress,merge,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
% \bibliographystyle{naturemag-doi}
\begin{document}
\citet{Lin}
\bibliography{ms_V1}
\end{document}
```

[image]